# Apache on Docker: set file permissions in a shared web hosting environment

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker. I'm trying to switch from a traditional VMs setup to a dockerized one for a bunch of websites I manage. I tried with Docker Compose and Wordpress, this is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  blog2:
    image: wordpress:4.9.6-apache
    volumes:
      - blog2:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:

volumes:
    blog2:
```

It works and it creates a `blog2` volume I can access on the main filesystem from `/var/lib/docker/volumes/blog2`. I can also connect with SFTP and edit files, everything works.
Files in the `/var/www/html` directory are owned by www-data user. If I edit them it's ok but if I add a new file... it is owned by the user I'm using on the server (in my test case it's root, but it can be any other user). So they cannot be modified by www-data, if the webserver need to edit or delete them.

How can I fix this problem? My idea is to add a user to every Docker container, add him to the www-data group and chown the entire /var/www/html to this user, so that initial and future files can be red or written by both, no matter if they are created by www-data or this user.

Can it work? And can I write it in the docker-compose.yml file to have this set up when I do `docker-compose up -d` at container creation? :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem is to start the wordpress container using a different user. This is documented under Running as an arbitrary user on the [dockerhub page for the wordpress image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/).

Inside the docker compose file you can set the user that will be running inside the container. For instance, you can specify user 1000 which will map to user 1000 on the machine.
Thus you can find the uid of user `www-data` and use that uid to start the container:

```
...
services:
  blog2:
    image: wordpress:4.9.6-apache
    user: 1000:1000  
    volumes:
      - blog2:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
...
```